# htaccess redirect all to www except one domain

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, vhosts

I'm trying to configure my `.htaccess` so that all domains `alldomains.*` point to `www.alldomains.*`.

I that solved this way:

```
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ www \.<br>
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Http://www.% {HTTP_HOST} / $ 1 [R = 301, L]
```

Now I want all domains `alldomains.*` to point to `www.alldomains.*`, except for `dev.mydomain.com`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301, L]
```